# Jekyll multiversion documentation

Tags: jekyll

I'm using Jekyll for documentation website, and now I have to support multiple versions. The idea is very simple:

```
_posts/
    v1.0.0/
        page1.md
        page2.md
    v1.0.1/
        page1.md
        page2.md
```

In this case I want to see these pages at the final website:

```
https://URL/v1.0.0/page1/
https://URL/v1.0.0/page2/

https://URL/v1.0.1/page1/
https://URL/v1.0.1/page2/
```

And I do *not* want to add `/v1.0.0/` in `permalink:` by myself: all `.md`-pages in subdirectory (for example, in `v1.0.0`) should contain name of this subdirectory as a *prefix* in the final URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the posts folder, use directories and pages directly.

```
v1.0.0/ 
   page1.md 
   page2.md 
 v1.0.1/ 
   page1.md 
   page2.md
```

That would generate the desired output without using permalinks in front matter.